# Error trying to create an start automatic using "Start Virtual Machine" template

Tags: azure, azure-automation

I've created a template but trying to change it or creating a new one; I receive the msg below:

The template validation failed: 'The value for the workflow parameter 'EmailID' at line '1' and column '5022' is not provided.'.

Answer (score 0):

In my case inserting an email on the relevant field solved the problem

Comment: In this case it's already filled